# When should we use Record<string, T> vs. { [index: string]: T }?

Tags: typescript

It seems `Record` must have been added for a reason, but the [announcement](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) and [Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) doesn't explain why.

```
const x: { [index: string]: number } = { f: 2, 3: 5 };
const y: Record<string, number> = { f: 2, 3: 5 };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Record` is usually used with a union of keys to get a type that contains those keys (ex: `Record<'a' | 'b', string > == { a:string, b:string}`)

If instead of a union of keys you pass in `string` this will resolve to an index signature, so the two type mention in the question are equivalent.

Which one you use is mostly a matter of style. If the type I define has nothing but the index signature, I prefer `Record`. If the type is more complex, then we need to spell out the index signature.

Comment: For more context for people reading this, this leads to an error: `const x: { [index: "a" | "b"]: number } = { 'a': 5 }`.

Comment: @MaxHeiber Use _in_ instead of colon: `const x: { [index in "a" | "b"]: number } = { a: 5, b: 3 }`.