# Recursive type name

Tags: typescript

I want to create an object which can have either primitives or objects like itself as properties. I mean something like that would be wrong:

```
const obj: DesiredType = {
  correctProp1: 'string',
  correctProp2: 123,
  correctProp3: true,
  wrongProp4: [1, 2, 3],
  prop5: {
    wrongProp1: () => {},         // Is neither an object nor a primitive
    wrongProp2: [1, 2, 3],        // Same
    correctProp3: 'other string'
  }
}
```

I don't want to just use `Record<string, any>`, because this way anything can be put there (function, array, etc). Using something like following:

```
Record<string, string | number | boolean | Record<string, any>>
```

would also be bad, because anything can appear on the second level

I have tried this:

```
type PrimitiveOrObject = string | number | boolean | Record<string, PrimitiveOrObject>; // ts(2456) type 

DesiredType = Record<string, PrimitiveOrObject>;
```

But I get error ts(2456): Type alias "PrimitiveOrObject" circularly references itself.

So is there a way to create a type alias for objects which contain either primitives or objects like itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a type alias generically in the same definition that creates it. But you can use it in object type literals, so if we add a little bit of indirection, we can get the recursion you want.

```
type PrimitiveOrObject =
  string | number | boolean | { [key: string]: PrimitiveOrObject };
```

The `{ [key: string]: PrimitiveOrObject }` syntax is called an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures). For the key type of `string`, it's equivalent to `Record` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902585/when-should-we-use-recordstring-t-vs-index-string-t) for details), but it has the benefit of being inside an object literal and thus not subject to the recursion restriction you've run afoul of.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to Silvio's answer that it is not a question of indirection, object type or index signature.

For example an additional indirection makes the problem come back:

```js
type PrimitiveOrObject = string | number | boolean | F<PrimitiveOrObject>;
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ PrimitiveOrObject circularly references itself

type F<T> = { [k: string]: T }
```

And other type compositions have the same behaviour as the object with an index signature

```js
type PrimitiveOrObject = string | number | boolean | PrimitiveOrObject[];
//                                  works just fine  -------------------
```

I think a good mental model to have is that a type alias declaration can only mention itself in a type composition with a built-in type constructor. Any utility type is going to make TS give up, probably because it has no general way to know when to stop recurring while checking the type definition. Built-in type constructors are known special cases which can have baked-in behaviour regarding recursion.